# Calculating area of intersection of rectangles in java

Tags: java, area, rectangles

I have a problem with one algorithm. I suppose to calculate the area of intersection of 2 rectangles(both are paraller to the OX and OY).
The rectangle(let's call it A) is described by (x1,y1,x2,y2) upper left corner(x1,y1) and lower right corner (x2,y2), the secodn will be B (x3,y3,x4,y4). 
I thought about one algorithm but it seems lame.

```
if(all of the points of rectangle A are inside of rectangle B)
     calculate(A);
else if(all of points the points of rectangle B are in A)
     calculate(B);
else if(x1 y1 is inside rectangle B)
        if(x1 is on the left from x3){
            if(y1 is under the y3)
         else
        }
```

etc. it will be so long and silly.

Comment: Consider `java.awt.geom.Area`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems a bit inefficient, because as I think of, the problem is *separable* and can be extended to 3 or more dimensions.

It's sufficient to calculate the overlapping *width* in dimension x, and the overlapping *height* in dimension y and multiply those.

(In case the rectangle doesn't overlap in some dimension, then that value is 0)

Overlapping detection happens by comparing the min_x, max_x values of each rectangle:

```
 <------>  <------->   vs.  <-----> <----->
 a      b  c       d        c     d a     b
 Thus if b<=c OR a>=d, then no overlapping length = 0

 <------------->   or   <------------->
 a    <---->   b        a       <------------->
      c    d                    c     b       d
 + the 2 symmetric cases (swap ab & cd)
```

From the last rows the endpoint of the common area is *minimum* of d & b;
The start point of the common area is the *maximum* of a & c.

Then the common area is min(d,b) - max (a,c) -- what if this is negative?
Well, you've just checked the conditions at the first row...

Comment: Yes I want to calculete this overlaping width and height but how I can do it? It is not said that they even overlap anywhere.